# Não consigo fazer a função "putchxy" da <conio2.h> funcionar

Tags: c

Oi. Eu comecei o curso o curso de ciência da computação esse ano e até então nunca tinha conseguido estudar nada de programação, então talvez seja por isso que eu esteja tendo erros tão básicos assim.

Meu problema de agora é com a biblioteca  em C, que tenho que usar para fazer o trabalho final da minha matéria, que é um jogo.

A professora passou algumas atividades pra gente ir aprendendo a usar a conio, mas por enquanto a única coisa que eu consegui fazer foi instalar ela hahaha A primeira atividade fora isso era "2) Implemente uma função void que imprime uma letra lida do teclado na posição (x, y)
utilizando as funções da Conio.". Procurando nas funções da , achei que a função "putchxy" faz exatamente isso, mas ao colocar ela no meu programa e compilar, acho que ela não está fazendo absolutamente nada, pois ela deveria imprimir o caracter lido e não faz isso.
Usei valores arbitrários definidos dentro do programa para x e y.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio2.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
    char ch;
    int x = 5, y = 5;

    printf("Digite uma letra no teclado:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    void putchxy (int x, int y, char ch);

    return (0);
}
```

Como essa foi a última aula, estou bem em dúvida ainda se estou fazendo certo. Mas olhando os slides passados em aula, lendo sobre a função dentro da própria biblioteca, procurando casos parecidos aqui no stack overflow, não consegui encontrar nada que me indicasse algum erro em meu código.

Já tentei escrever de outras formas, tentei criar eu mesmo uma outra função, tentei inverter, colocar os próprios números, mas além dessa forma nenhuma outra compila propriamente.

Onde foi que eu errei?

Comment: O erro está em usar a `conio`, ela é considerada obsoleto e não padrão.

Comment: É um trabalho para uma matéria do primeiro semestre do curso, acho que você pode perdoar né

Comment: E para alem de não ser padrão nem é utilizável noutros sistemas operativos como Mac ou linux, o que torna o seu código não portável. Posto este aparte, você apenas definiu a função `putchxy` ao invés de a chamar

Comment: Mas como eu faria isso? Eu tentei de algumas formas, mas em nenhuma delas deu certo, pensei que esse poderia ter sido meu erro, mas olhando as formas que encontrei de fazer isso, não deu.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui descobrir a resposta, vou responder aqui pro caso de mais alguém ter as mesmas dificuldades.

Foram dois erros:

1. Eu não fiz a chamada da função corretamente durante a main, apenas tinha declarado ela. Eu até tinha tentado de outras formas, mas pelo meu segundo erro elas não deram certo e me fizeram crer que estariam erradas também.
2. O segundo erro foi quanto à instalação da biblioteca  no Code::Blocks. Apesar de quando ter instalado eu ter adicionado o endereço ao linker, por algum motivo (talvez eu tenha esquecido de apertar o "Ok" ao sair) ele não salvou isso e por tal motivo quando eu executava a função, ele apenas me informava que estava indefinida.

Não sei se consigo explicar da melhor forma, mas queria apenas deixar formalmente aqui a resolução do meu problema pro caso de mais alguém ter esse problema. Muito obrigado a todos que realmente ajudaram e qualquer sugestão ou comentário, eu aceito de bom grado.

Essa foi minha primeira pergunta no fórum.

O código de forma correta, ficou:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio2.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()

{
char ch;
int x = 5, y = 5;

printf("Digite uma letra no teclado:\n");
scanf(" %c", &ch);
putchxy (x, y, ch);

return (0);
}

void putchxy (int x, int y, char ch);
```